# C Encrypt data in file.txt

Tags: c, encryption, passwords

I have problem in encrypting my plain text in C.
I am able to write and read the file in C 
Inside the text:

```
ID  Promo   Points  Password    Name
1   NONE    0       awdawdawd   daw
```

Which in this case it just print password in plain text, Is it possible to encrypt the data any method, which shows like this:

```
ID  Promo   Points  Password    Name
1   NONE    0      ENCRYPTEDDATA daw
```

Of course the password wont be "ENCRYPTEDDATA", I just want it avoid plain text which user can easily see the file. 
The reason I create file cause I need to read it from the file and make a login function. 
My program itself able to decrypt the password when in request of checking id and password.
It can use any method only the program can encrypt and decrypt the data
Any solution guys?
If possible I also need to limit the encrypted text

Comment: One of the simplest solutions is encoding and decoding using xor combination of password text and a static internal key. But there are a lot of more secure algorithms - mostly available as ready-to-use library (or source code). I tried google "password encryption c" and found some (including the suggested but not recommended [XOR encryption](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/Simple-XOR-Encryption-Decryption-in-Cpp)).

Comment: Amongst many others, see [Secure Salted Password Hashing — How to do it properly](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

Comment: Also note the recent Coding Horror blog on [Hacker, Hack Thyself](https://blog.codinghorror.com/hacker-hack-thyself/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hash password with strong hash function like SHA2 and  store the hash in your file rather than storing it in plain

Hashing might be better in this case than encryption, as for encryption you will have to worry about storing key somewhere securely.

When your login function needs to validate incoming password, you can just hash incoming password and match it against the hashed password from you file

Comment: @JoesLie:  While Pras' answer doesn't provide a decryption method, the logic is sound for a secure solution....  Provided the text file holding the password has strictly limited access.

Comment: Indeed. This is the way to design such a *login system*, in the real world. Passwords should be hashed one-way (with a *salt*, unique per user), so that if an attacker gets hold of the hashes the attacker can't merely decrypt to find out what the passwords were.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect your login then you should use a password hash, also known as a Password Based Key Derivation Function. These functions are *often*, but not always, based on a secure hash. You **should not** use a cryptographic hash such as SHA-2 for this purposes.

Common password hashes are PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Argon2 is the most advanced one as winner of the password hashing competition. A password hash differs from a normal hash in two important aspects:

1. it uses key strengthening techniques to make it harder for adversaries to use a dictionary or brute force attack (in the form of an iteration count or work factor and possibly additional memory / threading related parameters);
2. it uses a salt - stored with the password hash - to avoid rainbow table attacks and to avoid duplicate hash values - which would show that an identical password is being used.

So although Pras is right about not using encryption I would not recommend a secure hash *unless you are sure that the password is large enough and unique*. In general those restrictions can nor should be enforced on password based authentication systems.